# Programmatically click UITextField ios4

Tags: ios4, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I'm trying to programmatically click a UITextField after the user clicks on another UIButton, this way, when the user clicks the button, the keyboard will appear for the UITextField that the button corresponds to.  What I'm trying to do is almost the opposite of resignFirstResponder. I haven't found any way to do this so far, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIResponder's becomeFirstResponder method.